# iOS custom memory allocator

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-efficiency

I'm about to start writing an iOS game and I'm going to use mainly C++/C for the core gameplay logic.

I really like pre-allocating everything in the game and try to avoid any dynamic allocations as much as possible. With my own C++/C code it's not a big deal. However there are some ObjC libraries which I'd like to re-use and I'm not sure how to inject my custom memory allocator to Cocoa based classes.

Is there any central 'inject point' in Cocoa where I can do that?

Comment: Why are you trying to inject your custom memory allocator into other libraries?  This sounds like obsessive pre-optimization.

Comment: I'd like to know exactly how much memory is utilized and in what components.

Comment: @thedaian: On the contrary, injecting memory allocators is a key part of _measurement_, which is exactly how you optimize properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is all highly theoretical but you may be able to use [categories (Mac Developer Tips)](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) to override [NSObjects (Apple Developer)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) alloc and dealloc methods.